# Is there a shortcut for b && b.c && b.c.d ? b.c.d : "default";

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I want to set a constant with a value from a nested object property that can be undefined or set it to a default value, I can do this:

```
const a = b && b.c && b.c.d ? b.c.d : "default value";
```

I don't like this syntax because I find it unreadable. I prefer:

```
const a = b.c.d || "default value";
```

But this syntax fails if `b` or `c` is not an object (undefined). Is there a syntax for this kind of need?

Comment: you could always destructure with the default value in that

Comment: There's at least one TC39 proposal: [Optional Chaining for JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)

Comment: @DerekPollard Could you please elaborate? (or post your comment as an answer)

Comment: For destructuring, you could do `const { c: { d: a = "default value" } = {} } = b || {};`, but personally I find this a lot harder to read.

Comment: You could use lodash get method to achieve this.
Lodash also provides you a way to set a default value if the value isn't available 
// _.get(object, path, [defaultValue])

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the above

http://jsfiddle.net/vamshikrishna144/py02dm8L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work,

```
(b && b.c && b.c.d) || "default value"
```

Comment: You are taking the test and then logically or-ing it with "default value?" I see now, from the questions second example. But I don't think this is what he/she wants. In any case, you should add more description as to why you believe this is the solution